# Why Java String "a".getBytes("UTF-16") get result [-2,-1,0,97]?

Tags: java, unicode, utf-16

```
"a".getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_16);
```

result: `[-2, -1, 0, 97]`

Why? Where does `[-2,-1...]` come from?

Comment: They are the "Byte Order Mark", or BOM.

Comment: It is BOM: FEFF (FE=-2 and FF=-1), then you have 97 (00 97decimal) as character a